# My output device stops and restarts the file then resuming after pause

Tags: c#, wpf, naudio

```
private void PlayPause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   audioFile = new AudioFileReader($@"D:\kondio.mp3"); tru1 = true;

   if (!tru)
   {
       PlayImage.Source = BitmapToImageSource(Resource1.pause);
       tru = true;
       outputDevice = new WaveOutEvent();
       if (outputDevice != null && audioFile!=null)
       {
           outputDevice.Init(audioFile);
           dispatcherTimer.IsEnabled = true;
           
           outputDevice?.Play();
           dispatcherTimer.Start();
       }
   }
   else
   {
       PlayImage.Source = BitmapToImageSource(Resource1.play);
       tru = false;
       outputDevice?.Pause();
       dispatcherTimer.IsEnabled = false;
   }
```

I'm very new to wpf and coding in general..
My question is about my NAudio Music player prototype.
I did a music player in Forms and all the NAudio stuff worked perfectly fine, but on WPF my play/pause button doesn't function properly.
The pause part restarts the player instead of pausing it.
I've tried taking the audioFile initiation out of this function and putting it in the wpf_load method but it gives an error istead.

Hope my problem isn't just me being really dumb and isn't a repost.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Post full code pls

Comment: I did in the comments bud

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using NAudio.Wave;
using Brushes = System.Windows.Media.Brushes;

namespace MusicPlayer
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private WaveOutEvent outputDevice;
        private AudioFileReader audioFile;
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
        TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan();
        bool tru = false; 
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        BitmapImage BitmapToImageSource(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Save(memory, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                memory.Position = 0;
                BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapimage.BeginInit();
                bitmapimage.StreamSource = memory;
                bitmapimage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bitmapimage.EndInit();

                return bitmapimage;
            }
        }
        private void MusicPlayer_Load()
        {

            dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
            this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
            Seekbar.Maximum = audioFile.TotalTime.Seconds;
            Seekbar.Minimum = 0;
            PlayImage.Source = BitmapToImageSource(Resource1.play);
            timeSpan = audioFile.TotalTime;
        }
        private void PlayPause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool check = false;
            if (check)
            {
                audioFile = new AudioFileReader($@"D:\kondio.mp3");
                check = true;
            }
            if (!tru)
            {
                PlayImage.Source = BitmapToImageSource(Resource1.pause);
                tru = true;
                outputDevice = new WaveOutEvent();
                if (outputDevice != null)
                {
                    
                    outputDevice.Init(audioFile);
                    dispatcherTimer.IsEnabled = true;
                    
                    outputDevice?.Play();
                    dispatcherTimer.Start();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                PlayImage.Source = BitmapToImageSource(Resource1.play);
                tru = false;
                outputDevice?.Pause();
                dispatcherTimer.IsEnabled = false;
            }
 
        }

        private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (Seekbar.Value != Seekbar.Maximum)
            {
                Seekbar.Value = Convert.ToInt32(audioFile.CurrentTime.TotalSeconds);
                
            }

        }

        private void Sound_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void SoundImage_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
                SoundImage.Source = BitmapToImageSource(Resource1.sound100hover);
        }
        private void SoundImage_MouseLeave()
        {
            SoundImage.Source = BitmapToImageSource(Resource1.sound100);
            Sound.Background = Brushes.White;
        }

    }
}
            }
 
        }
```

The PlayImage.Source is for the button to change it's image.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).